# how to list the resources requested by an iframe

Tags: javascript, networking, iframe, resources

I am trying to build a webpage that will show the resources requested by a 3rd party iframe.

Something that gives a similar output to the network tab in google chrome developer tools (but not so flashy).

Do you guys know any javascript functions that may help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no JavaScript functions that will allow you to do so in browser on your web page as you can't access content of frames if it is not on your domain (same origin policy).

You may be able to have browser's extension that do so. Another option is to parse/render 3rd party page on server and detect used resources, than send results to your page.